# SKLearn Kernel PCA "Precomputed" argument

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to perform Kernel PCA using scikit-learn, using a kernel that is not in their implementation (and a custom input format that is recognized by this kernel).  It would probably be easiest if I could just compute the kernel ahead of time, save it, and then use it in Kernel PCA.

The `precomputed` argument to KernelPCA would imply that I am able to do what I want; however, it's not explained in the documentation, and I can't find any examples of it being used.  Even in [the unit test source code for KernelPCA in sklearn](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/source/browse/src/python/scikits.learn/PLATLIB/sklearn/decomposition/tests/test_kernel_pca.py?repo=xy-27&name=v2.7.6.0), the code doesn't ever seem to actually say what the precomputed kernel is.

Does anyone know how I would use my own precomputed kernel?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The precomputed kernel that you need to use at fit time is the gram matrix between the samples. I.e. if you have `n_samples` samples denoted by `x_i`, then you need to give to `fit` as first parameter the matrix `G` defined by `G_ij = K(x_i, x_j)` for `i, j` between `0` and `n_samples - 1`.

E.g. for the linear kernel this is

```
def linear_kernel(X, Y):
    return X.dot(Y.T)

X = np.random.randn(10, 20)
gram = linear_kernel(X, X)
```

For prediction on `X_test` you need to pass

```
X_test = np.random.randn(5, 20)
gram_test = linear_kernel(X_test, X)
```

This is to be seen in the unit tests, e.g. [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/decomposition/tests/test_kernel_pca.py#L139)

Comment: I had a comment here earlier asking about this, but just as a note to anyone who uses this question (since the Kernel PCA documentation is unclear about this) -- the input for "transform" should be a kernel matrix K(test instances, training instances).  If you do it the other way around, you'll get "broadcasting operands" errors.  If you try to transform an instance directly you will also get these errors, you need to transform the kernel matrix; this doesn't seem to make sense at first since you're getting a transformation of the original data but not sending the original data.

Comment: Thanks for this -- I may have defined the linear kernel the wrong way round from what is used in scikit-learn. Yes: If you get the order wrong, it will not work. Is your kernel matrix fixed or would you be able to devise a function that returns the kernel values? Because in that case you can also pass this function, avoiding headaches about how the prediction gram matrix must be ordered.

Comment: The kernel matrix comes from calling a function k(X,Y).